# React-router activeClassName not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For some reason, when I load/refresh the page in my app, the correct link is shown as active. When I click on a different link, it works as expected and becomes active, however the original link is also showing up as active.

UPDATE: I've just realised that when I click anywhere outside the menu bar, the active link loses its active status aswell, but the original link remains active. Essentially, when I click elsewhere, the menu returns to the example given in the first screenshot, even though the route URL is different.

Perhaps easier to demonstrate with screenshots:

[image]

This is shown on page load/refresh - as expected

[image]

But click on another link, and both of them now show as active

[image]

Click on another one, and the active link changes, but the original one is still showing as active as well

Here's my code:

One of the link elements (they are all identical, apart from SVG code and labels):

```
const AnnouncementLink = (props) => {
    return(

        <Link   to="/announcements" 
                className={styles.assignmentLinkHolder} 
                activeClassName={styles.activeLinkHolder}
                onClick={()=>props.hideSlideOver()}>
            <span className={styles.iconHolder}>
                <svg>
                  //Lots of SVG code here!
                </svg>
                <span className={styles.label}>
                    Announcements
                </span>
            </span>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

The menu element in full (not including some of the variable declarations which aren't relevant):

```
const photo = require('../../images/profilePics/blankface.jpg');

const SideMenu = (props) => {

    //VARIABLE DECLARATIONS...

    return (
        <div className={styles.sideMenu}>
            <img src={photo} className={styles.profilePic} />
            <div className={styles.menuItem}>
                <DashboardLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
                <CoursesLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
                <AssignmentsLink    hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} 
                                    badge={totalAssignments} />
                <UsersLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
                <AnnouncementsLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
                <ReportsLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
                <DiscussionsLink hideSlideOver={props.hideSlideOver} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )   
}
```

And the React-router parent:

```
const Admin = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={Academy}>
                    <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard" />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/courses" component={CoursesMenu} />
                    <Route path="/assignments" component={AssignmentsMenu} />
                    <Route path="/users" component={UsersMenu} />
                    <Route path="/announcements" component={AnnouncementsMenu} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>

    )
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the size of the screenshots - didn't realise they'd be that big until I'd already posted the question!

Comment: Try to remove string of code with `IndexRedirect` from router. Please do not forget to write result of problem solving.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I've been offline for a few days. Tried taking away IndexRedirect but hasn't made any difference - any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seem to have resolved it - not sure if this is a proper solution or just a workaround, but it seems to have done the trick.

The answer lies in the `<SideMenu>` component. By giving it a prop of `path` and linking this to the changing URL, it rerenders the component each time the URL changes. Also by removing `<IndexRedirect>` as suggested by oklas and changing it to `<Route to='/'>`, it prevents the active class from sticking on the `<DashBoard>` link.

Here's the code - this is from a section of the app that wasn't referenced above - the parent of `<SideMenu>`

```
<div className={styles.container}>
    <SideMenu path={this.props.children.props.route.path} /> { //This 'path' property solves the problem by rerendering the SideMenu component every time the path changes }
    <ViewPort>
        {this.props.children}
    </ViewPort>
</div>
```